# How to correct linker path in LibreElec build system?

Tags: linker

I have been trying to add a series of packages to OpenElec and I frequently come across a linker problem,

*libtool: link: cannot find the library `=/home/hansen/Documents/NEWELEC/LakkaElec/Lakka-LibreELEC/build.LibreELEC-Generic.i386-8.2-devel/toolchain/i686-libreelec-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/lib/libglapi.la' or unhandled argument`=/home/hansen/Documents/NEWELEC/LakkaElec/Lakka-LibreELEC/build.LibreELEC-Generic.i386-8.2-devel/toolchain/i686-libreelec-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/lib/libglapi.la'*

I think the problem/why the linker cant locate the library is because of the '=' before the address. However I am unable to find the cause of this.

Comment: You get any error?

Comment: yes, "make: *** [Makefile:475: glfont] Error 1" @RenatoAfonso